# Polar Equation to Cartesian Equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polar-coordinates

Find the cartesian equation of the circle with polar equation $r=2a\cos \theta$

My attempt,

Since $\cos \theta=\frac{x}{r}$

So, $r=2a(\frac{x}{r})$

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$r = 2a(x/r)$ implies $r^2 = 2ax$ but $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ as well. Combining these gives $x^2 - 2ax + y^2 = 0$ and tidying up gives $(x-a)^2 + y^2 = a^2$

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$x=r\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\theta$$
We can substitute in for $r$:
$$x=2a\cos^2\theta,\quad y=2a\cos\theta\sin\theta$$
We can say that
$$\cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2a}}$$
and, by the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$,
$$\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{2a}}$$
You now have expressions for $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ as functions of $x$, which you can plug into the equation for $y$:
$$y=2a\sqrt{\frac{x}{2a}}\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{2a}}$$
All you have to do now is simplify. You can multiply the roots together, then try to change the expression inside the square root to resemble a more familiar equation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a circle? I would expect the equation of a circle to be $r = a$.
Recall that $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt { x^2 + y^2 } &=& 2a \frac{x}{r} \\
x^2 + y^2 &=& 4a^2 \frac{x^2}{r^2} \\
x^2 -  4a^2 \frac{x^2}{r^2} + y^2 &=& 0 \\
(1 - \frac{4a^2}{r^2})x^2 + y^2 &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}